# Install issue with VUE.js JavaScript

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-pack

When I am trying to install NPM package in my machine. Getting this error.

[image]

This is the debug.log file [click here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tt672h8j_-NjAIMueVnfMNz7yI0vWSyp)

Comment: Removed tags from title; trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization; grammar. Please add the error message as text, not as an image. No one can find this question (and their answers) in the future if it doesn't mention the error text.

Answer (score 1):

From this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/990) and this [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072) it seems that there is a problem with the npm cache which in turn problem of the certain npm mirror of what you are using.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

do this and install it again. This seems to fix the problems.